# Have both iPhone & watch app start?

Tags: ios9, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I have created a companion Apple Watch app, and want to sync data between the phone and the watch.

Is there a way to get both apps to load at the same time? If I open the iPhone app, the watch app doesn't open, and vice versa.

Comment: Why do you need both apps to open at the same time?

Comment: So that I can sync data between them. I am using applicationContext to push data between apps. The iphone app never gets the update until I open it.

Comment: That is expected and intentional behavior. If you have a specific issue syncing data, you should describe the problem and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force a counterpart app to open in the foreground, but it's not necessary for it to be open.

An app *doesn't* need to be open before you can transfer context data to it.  The system sends that data in the background, even if the counterpart app is *not* open.

Once you *do* open the counterpart app, `receivedApplicationContext` is called to deliver the waiting data.

> Use the updateApplicationContext:error: method to communicate recent state information to the counterpart. **When the counterpart wakes, it can use this information to update its own state.**

You're already using the proper method to sync data between devices, and the transfer works as Apple intended.  It's much more efficient to transfer data in the background to be on hand, than to wait for an app to be open *before* transferring data to it.